# How to parse/unmarshall yaml into data structure

Tags: go, yaml

I have the following yaml which I would like to parse to Go

```
env:
  production:
      asia:
          blue: config.prod-asia
      ph:
          blue: prod.ph.config.blue
          green: prod.phconfig.green
  staging:
      asia:
          blue: asia.config.blue
      ph:
          blue: phconfig.blue
          green: ph.config.green
```

However I tried the following structure does not work.

```
type env struct {
    Env map[string]region `yaml:"env"`
}

type region struct {
    Region map[string]config
}

type config map[string]string
```

How should I build my structure so I can parse into a data structure as follows?

```
func main() {
    var d env

    source, err := ioutil.ReadFile("config.yaml")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Couldn't read yaml file.")
    }

    err = yaml.Unmarshal(source, &d)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Couldn't parse yaml file.")
    }

    fmt.Println(d)
}
```

The output when run above is

```
# go run .
{map[production:{map[]} staging:{map[]}]}
```

yaml lib used `"gopkg.in/yaml.v2"`

Comment: If your code doesn't work: What does the error tell you?

Comment: There is no error ...just the output does not show it all @Volker

Comment: Which yaml library are you using?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn see above

Comment: `Region map[string]config` means you expect a yaml key of `Region` (or `region`), but that does not exist in your input.

Answer (score -1):

```
type env struct {
    Env map[string]map[string]map[string]string `yaml:"env"`
}
```

solved it with the above example